# Why I am I getting error ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax? Have I typed it correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if shape_b=="CUBE":
    a=int(input("Please enter the measure of the edge of cube"))
    volume=a*a*a
    TSA=6a*a
    CSA=4a*a
    print(f"Volume of cube is {str(volume)}. TSA is {str(TSA)}. CSA is str{CSA}")`
```

**error; TSA=6a*a          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Please help me out.

Comment: What is `6a`? If it is a variable, you can't start with number, if it is a number multiplier, you should do `6*a*a`

Comment: Oh, thanks. It was my mistake. Please delete the question

Comment: @vvp4 on a side note - you don't need the `str(...)` in your format string... `str` gets applied to the objects by default

Comment: but dont i need to conver the integer to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a little mistake. `6a*a` is replaced by `6*a*a`

```
if shape_b=="CUBE":
    a=int(input("Please enter the measure of the edge of cube"))
    volume=a*a*a
    TSA=6*a*a
    CSA=4*a*a
    print("Volume of cube is {}. TSA is {}. CSA is {}".format(volume, TSA, CSA))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do this:

```
TSA=6*a*a
CSA=4*a*a
```

Comment: Thank you very much.